# Jquery full version, 3.4, not .modal support

Tags: jquery

I have a problem where I need to use ajax and cookies, so I need to use the full jquery library. The import I'm using is this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
```

However, I have a modal and the .modal command does not work without the bootstrap library, as below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" name="codigoProduto" id="codigoProduto">

              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                            ...
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(
$("#codigoProduto").on('dblclick',function() {        
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");

})
);
```

If I leave only the Bootstrap library 3.3.1, the code works normally.

Imports:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: So use the bootstrap version, but don't make it slim...

Comment: If I use version 3.4 without the slim version, the .modal command does not work

Comment: So use 3.3.1 without the slim. Though, tbh, bootstrap will probably with with 3.4. There were no compatibility changes that should affect bootstrap in the 3.4 release. Your problem is likely due to the way you are including jquery and bootstrap, not the version you are using.

Comment: I added the biclotecas I'm using in the content

Comment: doesn't bootstrap require jquery to be included before bootstrap?

Comment: That was exactly the problem, it worked perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use bootstrap attributes without bootstrap? If you do not want to use bootstrap, you cannot use `data-dismiss`, or `.modal()`.

Instead, you could do something like:

```
$("#exampleModal").show();
```

and to hide, you could do something like:

```
$("exampleModal").removeAttr("style").hide();
```

But most of the classes are taken from bootstrap, and I do not understand why you'd not want to import bootstrap?

Comment: I added the biclotecas I'm using in the content